# GTK3 и нажатие на клавиатуру "C-GNU/LINUX"

Tags: c, gtk, linux

Как в *GTK* получить значение нажатой клавиши (какую клавишу пользователь нажал) с последующем выводом на экран?

Насколько я понял, это "должно" выгладить следующим образом:

```
mine()  
{  
создаем окно;  
создаем label "текст";  
g\_signal\_connect(главное окно,"key_press_event", G_CALLBACK (set_text), NULL);  
}  
set\_text(GtkWidget \*widget, GdkEventKey \*event, gpointer user\_data)  
{  
перерисовка label с текстом (нажата клавиша "некая клавиша допустим А");  
    gchar i = event->keyval;  
    gtk\_label\_set\_text (GTK\_LABEL (label),&i); __чтобы в переменную "i" помещалась буква которую я нажал__  
    g\_printf("button-press-event, %i \n", i);     
}
```

Comment: Что конкретно вам не понятно? Не работает приведенный вами пример?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696838/how-do-i-get-keyboard-and-mouse-input-in-gtk

Answer (score 1):

перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7697544/4827341) (оригинал в виде комментариев):

посмторите на примеры:

http://developer.gnome.org/gtk-tutorial/2.90/

в частности на этот:

http://developer.gnome.org/gtk-tutorial/2.90/x344.html

по второй ссылке — код клавиатурного *callback*-а, который похож на то, что вы хотите.